# Derivated distribution question

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

"The salary of a group of employees is represented by the continuous random variable $X$ with probability density function

$f_X(x)= \begin{cases}x/2  & \text{,$0\le x\le2$} \\
0 & \text{,else}
\end{cases}$

Additionally, the employees spend and amount $Y$ in food, given by the function of the salary $Y=(X-1)^2$.
What is the density function probability $f_Y(y)$?

My thoughts: first, I need to find the range of $Y$, which is $[0,1]$ (because $x$ varies between $0$ and $2$). Next,$y=(x-1)^2 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{y} +1$, so the Jacobian is $\mid J\mid$ $=|\frac{dx}{dy}|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$, so

$g_Y(y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y}+1)(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}})=\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}) & \text{, $0\le y\le1$} \\
0 & \text{, else}
\end{cases}$

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.    You can test your answer: $$\int_0^1 \dfrac 1 4 \left(1-\dfrac 1 {\surd{y}}\right) \operatorname d y = \dfrac 3 4 \neq 1$$

The transform you need is indeed: $f_Y(y) = f_X(x(y)) \rvert \frac{\mathrm d x(y)}{\mathrm d y} \lvert$

However, there are two errors:

1. Since $y= (x-1)^2$ is not invertable, there are actually two $x(y)$ functions, and each one contributes to the density.
2. $f_X(1\pm\surd y) = \frac 1 2 \color{red}{\neq \frac 1 2(1+\surd y)}$

So you want $$\begin{align}f_Y(y) & = f_X(1+\surd y)\lvert\frac{\mathrm d (1+\surd y)}{\mathrm d y} \rvert + f_X(1-\surd y)\lvert\frac{\mathrm d (1-\surd y)}{\mathrm d y} \rvert
\\ & = \frac 1{2\surd y}\; \mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}
\end{align}$$